# Powerpoint textbox not keeping size settings from placeholder

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I'm trying to develop an application that creates a powerpoint report using VB.NET. I've got a template slide set up which I copy for every page of the report. In the template there are some text placeholders and some image placeholders. I have the text placeholders set so they should rescale the text to fit within the placeholder area.

Currently I'm trying to do this by loading in the template, then using the duplicate method to copy the template slide as many times as required. Then I fill in each slide with the details. For some reason though, the text boxes don't keep the rescale text to fit the size setting or at least they don't enforce it. When I check the output the text often overflows but the setting is still correct. If I change it to a different setting then change it back the text rescales though. I tried doing that in code but it doesn't seem to work.

My previous method was to import the templates slide using the InsertFromFile method of the slides class. This did keep the formatting correct, but only after I imported the design and color scheme as well. The problem with this was in the master slide view it had a duplicate entry for every single slide that I'd imported and I've no idea how to only end up with one for all of them.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard please. It seems if I only apply the design and color scheme to the first slide it still applies them correctly to all the rest.